# Regex split by word or tag

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I use regular expressions in Javascript in order to split a text by words (utf8) or tags? For example, given the following:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor <b>sid</b> amet et <a href="asdasd">amet et</a> fugit
```

I'd like to have it splitted like this:

```
Lorem 
ipsum 
dolor 
<b>
sid
</b> 
amet 
et 
<a href="asdasd">
amet
et
</a>
fugit
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use this regex `<.+?>|\S+(?=<)|\S+`

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
myString.match(/<[^>]*>|[^\s<]+/g)
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this

```
(?s)(?:<.+?>)|(?:\S+)
```

You will get a list of matches.

Edited:

```
(?s)(?:<.+?>)|(?:\S+(?=<))|(?:\S+)
```